# Grayed menu toolbar icons are not drawn on Vista and up in WM_DRAWITEM

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

My application uses a so-called Internet Explorer-style menu bar, i.e. a toolbar that opens several drop down menus. `hbmpItem` is set to `HBMMENU_CALLBACK` so that my app can draw custom 24x24 icons on `WM_DRAWITEM`.

This is all working fine on Windows XP but on Vista (and up) no icons are drawn for grayed menu items. Menu items in normal state, however, are drawn fine on Vista too. But when an item is in grayed state, no icon gets drawn on Vista. Exception: When the user moves the mouse over a grayed item, the icon is drawn correctly. But all the other grayed items aren't drawn at all on Vista.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the reason for this behaviour?

Here is how I draw my icons on `WM_DRAWITEM`:

```c
case WM_DRAWITEM: {
    DRAWITEMSTRUCT *lpdis = (DRAWITEMSTRUCT *) lParam;

    if(!lpdis) return 0;

    if(lpdis->CtlType == ODT_MENU) {

        struct menuinfo *mi = (struct menuinfo *) lpdis->itemData;
        int ricon;
        HICON hIcon;

        if(lpdis->itemState & ODS_GRAYED) {
            ricon = mi->grayedicon;
        } else {
            ricon = mi->icon;
        }

        if(!(hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance_g, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ricon)))) return 0;

        DrawIconEx(lpdis->hDC,
            lpdis->rcItem.left - 16,
            lpdis->rcItem.top + (lpdis->rcItem.bottom - lpdis->rcItem.top - 24) / 2,
            hIcon, 24, 24,
            0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);

        DestroyIcon(hIcon);         

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;   
    }

case WM_MEASUREITEM: {
    MEASUREITEMSTRUCT *lpmis = (MEASUREITEMSTRUCT *) lParam;

    if(!lpmis) break;

    lpmis->itemWidth += 24;
    if(lpmis->itemHeight < 24) lpmis->itemHeight = 24;
    return TRUE;    
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

Sometimes parts of the icon are drawn. Here is a screenshot: You can see that the icons for undo, copy, paste, and delete aren't drawn. The icon for cut is partially drawn (it should be a full pair of scissors but only the bottom half of the icon is actually drawn). The icon for redo is drawn correctly only because the mouse cursor is currently over it. As soon as the mouse cursor leaves the item, the icon will disappear immediately.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try a debugger to see when `WM_DRAWITEM` is received?

Comment: Yes, it is received just fine and DrawIconEx() is called as well when the item is in grayed state but somehow no icon becomes visible unless the mouse is currently over the grayed item.

Comment: Why don't you use a plain menu and pass PARGB bitmaps. Then the system can draw it, and draw it themed.

Comment: Isn't that Vista only? I need to be compatible with XP too.

Comment: It looks like you're abusing HBMENU_CALLBACK and drawing outside the rcItem RECT provided by WM_DRAW_ITEM. You code also looks the code described in http://www.nanoant.com/programming/themed-menus-icons-a-complete-vista-xp-solution Are you processing the `WM_MEASUREITEM` message in the same fashion? Finally while that article suggests this should work on Vista, it ends up using a different method in order to match the system theme.

Comment: I've now included the `WM_MEASUREITEM` code. Please see above. Concerning your "drawing out of bounds" remark, I've just tried to have DrawIconEx() draw at rcItem.left and rcItem.top but it doesn't make a difference. The icons are still not drawn when calling DrawIconEx() like this:  DrawIconEx(lpdis->hDC,  lpdis->rcItem.left, lpdis->rcItem.top,   hIcon, 24, 24, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);

Comment: You need to use different code for XP. You have code that works on XP, and you can let the system do it right on Vista. If you draw it yourself like that on Vista and up then your menus will looks completely out of place. Why not let the system do it for you?

Comment: So does this mean that the route used above is simply incompatible with Vista? So is there really no way to make it work on both, XP and Vista? Then I'd be forced to go with PARGB bitmaps of course.

Comment: Time to stop supporting XP anyway.

Comment: It's certainly possible to draw your own menus on Vista and up. But why would you do so? The system will draw them in the native theme for you.

Comment: Well, I'd like to find out my mistake... there must be a reason why my approach doesn't work. Do you have a link to some example code that works on Vista too?

Comment: Alright, I'm simply setting `hbmpItem` to a PARGB HBITMAP on Vista and up now. This is probably really a better solution than trying to fix that old owner-draw code to work with Vista :) Another advantage of this method is that my menus appear in Vista-style now.